Getting layer last modified value with QGIS Expression
I am working on some revision tracking and would like to present information about when layers saved in a GeoPackage were last edited using an expression. I can create a custom function if necessary.
I have had a look in the QGIS Python API but can't find anything. Is there a way to find when a layer was last edited?


You could add a date-time-field to the layer, containing now() as default value, and force update that field upon feature creation or edit.

@Erik yep I am progressing with EditTime and EditUsr field for my main layers but am trying to avoid it for every layer that can be edited and has an impact on the output

The "Last modified" info seem to depend on data type (for exemple data stored in a file gdb seem to show the last time look at it (so now...), shapefile seem to show the spatial index (.sbn) last change, geopackage store it in the "gpkg_contents" table while other data source don't give any information). So you should state with witch format you work  as the solution may be quite different...

As you work in a geopackage (so a spatialite database) you may create an history table and populate it using trigger. This will let you not only record when last editing happen but also what edit has been made (an exemple : https://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html)

@J.R Thats a handy looking resource which I will hopefully get some time to review but its a little abstract for now, it did however get me to do some searching and I found the gpkg_contents table in standard geopackages created by QGIS which can be accessed through the database manager but I can't add the table to a qgis project.

For now, I can only suggest Python solutions that can be turned into a custom function via the Function Editor.
So, there is a polygon layer called 'polygon', which was the last modified on: 2024-12-03 09:31:33

There are several of them:

Through the getmtime() function from the os.path Python module:

Return the time of last modification of path. The return value is a
floating-point number giving the number of seconds since the epoch
(see the
time
module). Raise
OSError
if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.

# imports
from os.path import isfile, getmtime
from datetime import datetime
from qgis.core import QgsProject

# getting the vector layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon")[0]

# getting the file path of the data source
source_path = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split('|')[0]

# checking if the source is a file and get its last modified time
if isfile(source_path):
    # getting the last modified time using getmtime
    modified_time = getmtime(source_path)
    # formating the timestamp for readability
    formatted_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(modified_time).strftime('%A, %d. %B %Y %H:%M:%S')
    print(f"Last modified: {formatted_time}")
else:
    print("The layer source is not a file or its modification date cannot be determined.")


Utilizing the st_mtime() function from the os Python module:

Get the status of a file or a file descriptor. Perform the equivalent
of a stat() system call on the given path. path may be specified as
either a string or bytes – directly or indirectly through the
PathLike
interface – or as an open file descriptor. Return a
stat_result
object.

# imports
from os import stat 
from os.path import isfile
from datetime import datetime
from qgis.core import QgsProject

# getting the vector layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon")[0]

# getting the file path of the data source
source_path = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split('|')[0]

# checking if the source is a file and get its last modified time
if isfile(source_path):
    # using os.stat to get file metadata
    file_stats = stat(source_path)
    # getting the last modified time using st_mtime
    modified_time = file_stats.st_mtime
    # formating the timestamp for readability
    formatted_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(modified_time).strftime('%A, %d. %B %Y %H:%M:%S')
    print(f"Last modified: {formatted_time}")
else:
    print("The layer source is not a file or its modification date cannot be determined.")



The output is: Last modified: Tuesday, 03. December 2024 09:31:33

As @J.R mentioned in their comment, information about the last modification could be data-type dependent, see for example Vector Drivers for more details. So, when one uses the ogr module, it could provide you with the DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE parameter for a shapefile:

DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=YYYY-MM-DD: Modification date to write in DBF
header with year-month-day format. If not specified, current date is
used.

# imports
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from datetime import datetime
from osgeo import ogr

# getting the vector layer by its name
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon")[0]

# getting the file path of the data source
source_path = layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split('|')[0]

# openning the vector layer with ogr module
dataSource = ogr.Open(source_path)
daLayer = dataSource.GetLayer(0)

# getting the last modified time
modified_time = daLayer.GetMetadata_Dict().get('DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE')

print(f"Last modified: {modified_time}")



The output is: Last modified: 2024-12-03.

Not sure about no 3, but no 2 works fine for finding when any layer in a geopackage was edited which is pretty handy for what I am doing
